# Planetscale: Creating unique index fails when a date column has a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, planetscale

I created this table in Planetscale

```
CREATE TABLE `community` (
    `id` serial PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(256),
    `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT (now()),
    `last_updated_at` timestamp(2)
);
```

But if I try to create the this unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX email_unique_index ON community (`email`);
```

I get this error:

```
18:01:21    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX email_unique_index ON community (`email`)   Error Code: 1067. target: gili.-.primary: vttablet: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Invalid default value for 'created_at' (errno 1067) (sqlstate 42000) (CallerID: ewuobpfp487ve5g2p79l): Sql: "alter table community add UNIQUE INDEX email_unique_index (email)", BindVars: {REDACTED}  0.418 sec
```

I could create the same table and index in my local mysql instance.
I was able to create the index in planetscale after i removed `DEFAULT (now())` as show below.

```
CREATE TABLE `community` (
    `id` serial PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(256),
    `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp(2) NOT NULL,
    `last_updated_at` timestamp(2)
);
```

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX email_unique_index ON community (`email`);
```

Why does this happen in Planetscale? Is there a fix for it?

Comment: If you can afford to lose the precision of the `created_at` column you can change it to: `\`created_at\` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()` and the index `email_unique_index` should be created without problem. Otherwise you can directly ask the [PlanetScale :: Discussions](https://github.com/planetscale/discussion/discussions).

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem! You need to remove the `NOT NULL` constraint. That's the issue. Like this: `created_at timestamp(2) DEFAULT (now())`. That did it for me.

**Update:**
This is the corrected SQL without having to remove the NOT NULL constraint. The problematic part was `(now())`, which I changed to `now(2)`. I tested this in my Planetscale instance, and it worked.

```
CREATE TABLE `community` (
    `id` serial PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(256),
    `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT now(2),
    `last_updated_at` timestamp(2)
);
```

And this is how you do it with Drizzle ORM:

```
{
  createdAt: timestamp("created_at", { fsp: 2 })
    .notNull()
    .default(sql`now(2)`),
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos! But removing `NOT NULL` makes `created_at` optional in TypeScript, when in fact it isn't. I want to avoid that

Comment: @inginia. What are you using for the types? Prisma?

Comment: @CarlosGalarza I use drizzle orm https://orm.drizzle.team/

Comment: @Acework not yet :( I just set it manually

Comment: @inginia. Nice! I use the same! I just made it work on my DB. I will post the corrected query in the answer. Notice the `(now())` changes to `now(2)` that's the fix. It worked perfectly on my Planetscale instance. I will replicate it in my app as well!